# eclipse is not installing at all

Tags: eclipse, windows-vista

I've installed jdk-8u65-windows-i586.exe and downloaded the latest version of Eclipse IDE.

When I double click on the eclipse-inst-win31.exe absolutely nothing happens.

MY OS is Windows Vista.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a working java sdk in java_home variable - type java - version in cmd prompt
 If you don't, reinstall java sdk and eclipse it should start.

Comment: That's working fine. It's showing the latest version of jdk I installed.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the Eclipse installer (which is still a rather new part of the Eclipse downloads), just take one of the complete distributions (scroll down below the installer on the download page).

While the installer first needs to download additional pieces from the Internet, those distributions are ready to start developing.